# Sub setting panel data

Tags: r, statistics, economics

Very new, so let me know if this is asking too much.
I am trying to sub set panel data, in R, into two different categories; one that has complete information for variables and one that has incomplete information for variables. My data looks like this:

```
Person     Year Income Age Sex
    1      2003  1500   15  1
    1      2004  1700   16  1
    1      2005  2000   17  1
    2      2003  1400   25  0
    2      2004  1900   26  0
    2      2005  2000   27  0
```

What I need to do is go through each column ( not columns 1 and 2 ) and if the data is full for the variable ( variables are defined by the id in the first column and then the column name, in the picture above an example is person1Income) return that to a data set. Else put it in a different data set. Here is my meta code and an example of what it should do given the above data. Note: I call variables by their id name then the column name, for instance the variable person1Income would be the first three rows in column three.

```
for(each variable in all columns except 1 and 2 in data set) if (variable = FULL) { return to data set "completes" }
else {put in data set "incompletes"}
completes = person1Income, person2Income, person1Age, person2Age, person1Sex, person2 sex
incompletes = {empty because the above info is full}
```

I understand if someone can't answer this question completely, but any help is appreciated. Also if my goal is not clear, let me know and I will try to clarify.

tl;dr I can't yet explain it in one sentence so...sorry.

Edit: visualization of what I mean by complete and incomplete variables. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4kuM.jpg)

Comment: Are you looking to separate the complete from incomplete individuals? Does this answer help? [How to find balanced panel data in R (aka, how to find which entries in panel are complete over given window)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3112918/1290420)

Comment: Yes, I need to separate the complete individuals from incomplete individuals, but by column i.e. I need a list of individuals that are complete, in each column, and a list of ones that are incomplete in each column. The key difference from that question is I need which individuals have complete info, by column, and which ones don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your picture, here's a stab at what you want. It may be long-winded and others may have a more elegant way of doing it, but it gets the job done:

```
library("reshape2")

con <- textConnection("Person Year Income Age Sex
  1      2003  1500   15  1
  1      2004  1700   16  1
  1      2005  2000   17  1
  2      2003  1400   25  0
  2      2004  1900   NA  0
  2      2005  2000   27  0
  3      2003  NA   25  0
  3      2004  1900   NA  0
  3      2005  2000   27  0")
pnls <- read.table(con, header=TRUE)

# reformat table for easier processing
pnls2 <- melt(pnls, id=c("Person"))
# and select those rows that relate to values
# of income and age
pnls2 <- subset(pnls2,
              variable == "Income" | variable == "Age")

# create column of names in desired format (e.g Person1Age etc)
pnls2$name <- paste("Person", pnls2$Person, pnls2$variable, sep="")

# Collect full set of unique names
name.set <- unique(pnls2$name)
# find the incomplete set
incomplete <- unique( pnls2$name[ is.na(pnls2$value) ]) 
# then find the complement of the incomplete set
complete <- setdiff(name.set, incomplete) 

# These two now contain list of complete and incomplete variables
complete
incomplete
```

If you are not familiar with `melt`ing and the `reshape2` package, you may want to run it line by line, and examine the value of `pnls2` at different stages to see how this works.

**EDIT**: adding code to compile the values as requested by @bstockton. I am sure there is a much more appropriate R idiom to do this, but once again, in the absence of better answers: this works

```
# use these lists of complete and incomplete variable names
# as keys to collect lists of values for each variable name
compile <- function(keys) {
    holder = list()
    for (n in keys) {
        holder[[ n ]] <- subset(pnls2, pnls2$name == n)[,3]
    }
    return( as.data.frame(holder) )
}

complete.recs <- compile(complete)
incomplete.recs <- compile(incomplete)
```

Comment: This is awesome and works brilliantly. Thank you very much (you have no idea how much difficulty this has given me). It works like I described, but is there a way that I can get those variables to have the values they correspond to? Right now it is only returning the variable names; i.e. completes = "Person1Income" "Person2Income" "Person1Age". But I need those variables to equal the values they correspond to e.g. Person1Income = (1500,1700,2000)

Comment: @bstockton -- It would be great to know if the addition above finally hit the mark... Or if you found your own alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume this is in a data.frame with name == 'dfrm'

```
completes <- dfrm[ complete.cases(dfrm[-(1:2)]) ,]
incompletes <- dfrm[ !complete.cases(dfrm[-(1:2)]) ,]
```

Thanks to @WojciechSobala for noticing my missing parens. For the question of identifying which column the missing values are in one could create a list: The list of id's is simple. The identification of which columns have missing values is also fairly easy to provide, but I have no idea what you mean by "the values in that column that correspond to the id variable" since they are all NA. For the identification step, you can use:

```
apply(incompletes, 1, function(x) c(x[1], x[2], which(is.na(x[-(1:2)]))))
```

I see now what you are asking. I don't have a solution yet but let me show you a couple of R functions that *might* help when it comes to enumerating and working with the categories that are formed by cross-classifying on two column values:

```
dat <- structure(list(Person = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Year = c(2003L, 
2004L, 2005L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L), Income = c(1500L, NA, 2000L, 
1400L, 1900L, 2000L), Age = c(15L, 16L, 17L, 25L, 26L, 27L), 
    Sex = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Person", "Year", 
"Income", "Age", "Sex"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

completes <-  lapply( split(dat[ , 3:5], dat$Person), function(x)  sapply(x, function(y) { if( all( !is.na(y)) ) { y } else { NA} })  )

$`1`
$`1`$Income
[1] NA

$`1`$Age
[1] 15 16 17

$`1`$Sex
[1] 1 1 1


$`2`
     Income Age Sex
[1,]   1400  25   0
[2,]   1900  26   0
[3,]   2000  27   0

 incompletes <- lapply( split(dat[ , 3:5], dat$Person), function(x)  sapply(x, function(y) { if( !all( !is.na(y)) ) { y } else { NA} }) )

$`1`
$`1`$Income
[1] 1500   NA 2000

$`1`$Age
[1] NA

$`1`$Sex
[1] NA


$`2`
Income    Age    Sex 
    NA     NA     NA
```

Comment: You have to add closing parenthesis complete.cases(dfrm[-(1:2)] <- here.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. Kind of works, but it only returns the specific row(s) in which the "NA(s)" is/are. I need it to return the column which the "NA" is in and the values in that column that correspond to the id variable. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is what I mean by those values. Hope visualization helps. http://imgur.com/1uPC1

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am looking into those functions, as I am constantly dealing with panel data. Gauden came extremely close to solving the problem so I gave his answer the check mark, although he didn't totally solve it I am fairly certain now that the data is reshaped it shouldn't be too hard.